# Dependency Error Installing Postfix 3 on Centos 6

Tags: postfix, centos6

I'm trying to upgrade to Postfix 3 on Centos, using these instructions:

https://www.ryadel.com/en/postfix-3-install-setup-linux-centos-for-sending-mail-smtp-smtps-starttls/

However, I'm getting the following dependency errors:

```
$ sudo yum install postfix3
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities, replace, security
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.strencom.net
 * extras: mirror.strencom.net
 * remi-php56: mirror.netweaver.uk
 * remi-php72: mirror.netweaver.uk
 * remi-safe: mirror.netweaver.uk
 * updates: ftp.heanet.ie
gf                                                                                                                                                | 2.9 kB     00:00     
gf/primary_db                                                                                                                                     |  44 kB     00:00     
gf-plus                                                                                                                                           | 2.9 kB     00:00     
gf-plus/primary_db                                                                                                                                | 104 kB     00:00     
156 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package postfix3.x86_64 2:3.5.2-1.gf.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.2)(64bit) for package: 2:postfix3-3.5.2-1.gf.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libsasl2.so.3()(64bit) for package: 2:postfix3-3.5.2-1.gf.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libicuuc.so.50()(64bit) for package: 2:postfix3-3.5.2-1.gf.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libicui18n.so.50()(64bit) for package: 2:postfix3-3.5.2-1.gf.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libicudata.so.50()(64bit) for package: 2:postfix3-3.5.2-1.gf.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libdb-5.3.so()(64bit) for package: 2:postfix3-3.5.2-1.gf.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libicu-last.x86_64 0:50.1.2-17.el6.remi will be installed
---> Package postfix3.x86_64 2:3.5.2-1.gf.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.2)(64bit) for package: 2:postfix3-3.5.2-1.gf.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libsasl2.so.3()(64bit) for package: 2:postfix3-3.5.2-1.gf.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libdb-5.3.so()(64bit) for package: 2:postfix3-3.5.2-1.gf.el7.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: 2:postfix3-3.5.2-1.gf.el7.x86_64 (gf-plus)
           Requires: libsasl2.so.3()(64bit)
Error: Package: 2:postfix3-3.5.2-1.gf.el7.x86_64 (gf-plus)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.2)(64bit)
Error: Package: 2:postfix3-3.5.2-1.gf.el7.x86_64 (gf-plus)
           Requires: libdb-5.3.so()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Any advice on correcting these dependencies would be greatly appreciated.

Kind regards,

James

Comment: CentOS 6? Why on earth are you trying to use such an old distro? Just install CentOS 8; it already has Postfix 3.

Comment: Thanks Michael. Unfortunately, there are reasons outside my control that this server has to stay on Centos 6. I expect the content will be migrated to a new Centos 8 server later in the year and this one decommissioned. However, it would be useful to update Postfix as a stop-gap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to install **el7** packages, designed for CentOS 7 with **el6** packages, designed for CentOS 6.

You need to properly configure the repository you are using, and probably update to CentOS 7 or 8 as 6 is close to its end of life, in a few months.

Comment: This solved my problem. I changed my repository to el6 and downloaded the el6 key, and I was able to install Postfix 3 from that. However, I recognise that I need to replace this server with something more modern, and am looking to commission a Centos 8 server to replace it in the next few months.